# How to truncate the seconds of a timestamp column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, truncate, timestamp-with-timezone

i have a table with a date column in timestampz data type, example:

Table "power"

| date |
| --- |
| 2021-04-07 18:00:00 |
| 2021-04-07 18:01:01 |
| 2021-04-07 18:02:00 |
| 2021-04-07 18:03:00 |
| 2021-04-07 18:04:01 |

Some of the dates have an extra second at the end and i want to truncate it, so it looks like this

| date |
| --- |
| 2021-04-07 18:00:00 |
| 2021-04-07 18:01:00 |
| 2021-04-07 18:02:00 |
| 2021-04-07 18:03:00 |
| 2021-04-07 18:04:00 |

I tried `UPDATE power SET date = DATE_TRUNC('second', date) FROM power;` but it isn't working, hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code *should* work if you use `'minute'`, but you really don't want the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE power
    SET date = DATE_TRUNC('minute', date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ec6c8906d8eee9765b0ac4123ab48701) is a db<>fiddle.